# How to deal with the parameters with script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I print the args from:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  print('The sys.argv is :\n',sys.argv)
```

and find that all the parameters transfer into string and i don't know how to deal with it.

Command `python3 MAX_HEAPIFY.py [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] 2`

output: `['MAX_HEAPIFY.py', '[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]', '2']`

Comment: *"all the parameters transfer into string"*  they are received as a list of strings and *"i don't know how to deal with it"* well, what do you want to do with them?

Comment: @Jim i wanna treat those parameter as the type i wanna input, such as list or tuple, not 'tuple' or 'list'

Comment: Edit your question, add sample input, your attempt and what you want the list to actually look like; we can't sit here guessing.

Comment: @Jim I don't know how to deal with the string after it transfer into string.if i execute a code : ` arr = [x for x in list(sys.argv[1]) if x.isdigit() and int(x)]` it will give me a weird result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand that python accepts all input on the command line as strings. It is up to you to process the args in your code.

Ideally you would use `argparse` to make this more robust, but for this example you can run a command like this:

```
python3 MAX_HEAPIFY.py "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10" 2
```

Then you will use `my_list = sys.argv[1].split(",")` to process your first arg as a list.

Obviously you need to deal with typecasting and things specific to your logic, but I hope this gives you a starting point.

Edit:

If you need to convert `my_list` to a list of ints, you can use a list comprehension like this:

```
my_int_list = [int(i) for i in my_list if i.isdigit()]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i try anytime to deal with the string '[1,2,3...]' but all they fault.Actually, i can't find any other method to deal with it in official document.Thus the document is illuminated all the parameter will be transfer into string...

Comment: Did you try `my_list = sys.argv[1].split(",")`? That should convert your first param into a list of strings

Comment: Or you can use the dreaded [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval).